# Coerce result row into object

Tags: sql, mysql, grails, groovy

Is there a way to coerce the result row gotten from calling a stored procedure into a specific object so I can pass just a list of that object into the view?

I know I can use things like Node.list() to do this, but I am eventually going to replace getnodes() with a fairly complicated stored procedure that creates temp tables and does some optimised sql fu. But for now I am just working on the grails interaction.

So on MySQL side I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`255.255.255.255` PROCEDURE `getnodes`()
BEGIN
   select * from node;
END
```

On the grails controller I have the following:

```
def nodes = new ArrayList<Node>()

// collect all the nodes returned
sql.eachRow("{call getnodes()}") { 
    nodes.add(it as Node)
}

println "Nodes size is: " + nodes.size()
nodes.eachWithIndex { d, i ->
    println "$i : $d"
}
```

My plan is to then pass the nodes to the view.

The problem is that it blows up on the line:

```
nodes.add(it as Node)
```

Is this even possible? I mean this should just coerce right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ended up just looking up each node with Node.get(it.id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it shouldn't "just coerce". Regarding the following:

```
sql.eachRow("{call getnodes()}") { 
    nodes.add(it as Node)
}
```

The type of `it` is GroovyRowResult, so `it as Node` will call `GroovyRowResult.asType(Node.class)`

So this coercion will fail unless the author of this method specifically handles this conversion. As converting from GroovyRowResult to Node is fairly obscure, I don't think one should reasonably expect this case to be handled.

An obvious solution is to do the conversion yourself:

```
sql.eachRow("{call getnodes()}") {GroovyRowResult it ->

    Node node = // TODO: Code to convert it to a Node 
    nodes.add(node)
}
```

Alternatively, you could use meta-programming to override the `asType` method of `GroovyRowResult` such that it also handles conversion to Node.