# GroovyRowResult coerce into domain object

Tags: groovy

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE todouser
(
  id SERIAL,
  email varchar(80) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password varchar(80),
  registered boolean DEFAULT FALSE,
  confirmationUri varchar(280),
  CONSTRAINT todouser_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and class:

```
class TodoUser {
    Long id;
    String email;
    String password;
    String confirmationUri;
    boolean registered;
}
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
TodoUser user = sql.firstRow("""SELECT * FROM todouser WHERE email = $email""")
```

i.e. I want Groovy to handle the coercion of the GroovyRowResult into my basic POGO, instead of building it myself as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002329/coerce-result-row-into-object/2002437#2002437).

I think this is reasonable since GroovyRowResult implements Map and its just a Map key to POGO instance variable name mapping... something which Groovy has some kind of support for.

The problem is that, in the PostgreSQL table, 'confirmationUri' is actually showing up as 'confirmationuri'... so the mapping is failing because of the 'U' being in upper case in my POGO.

I have tried changing 'confirmationUri' to 'confirmation' in the table and POGO and it works... but just for the record, how would you get around this in Groovy?

I seem to remember there being methods you can override in Groovy classes which help in resolving "set/get" calls. But is this the right approach? Is there perhaps some annotation I could use to mark 'confirmationUri' as equivalent to 'confirmationuri' when 'get/set' methods are called? Or perhaps there's some other way to do this in Groovy?

Comment: I think your edit should be an answer to the question. Let others answer and the highest vote is arguably the best approach.

Comment: Thx Michael, I have taken your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing). Below are the changes to TodoUser (note: I have since changed the column name to 'confirmation_uri'):

```
class TodoUser {
    Long id;
    String email;
    String password;
    String confirmationUri;
    boolean registered;

    def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
        if(isConfirmationUri(name)) {
            this.confirmationUri = value
        } else {
            unknownProperty(name)
        }
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        if(isConfirmationUri(name)) {
            return confirmationUri
        } else {
            unknownProperty(name)
        }
    }

    def isConfirmationUri(String name) {
        'confirmation_uri'.equals(name)
    }

    def unknownProperty(String name) {
        throw new MissingPropertyException(name, this.class)
    }
}
```

This works as expected (in the manual test below and when actually using it to convert from a GroovyRowResult to a TodoUser):

```
TodoUser user = new TodoUser();

try {
    user.invalidProperty = 'http://blah.com'
} catch(MissingPropertyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Class type = e.getType()
    String prop = e.getProperty()
    println """Could not set the $prop property on type $type"""
}
user.confirmation_uri = 'http://blah.com'
println user.confirmationUri
```

That is one way of doing it. I don't see anything wrong with this approach (but maybe I'm wrong). Is there a better approach / is there anything wrong with this approach?